# How to find the coordinates of 0-value Pixels on MATLAB?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, matrix, pixel

I have an image of pixel values 1 and 0. The object in which I want to do trace has a pixel value of 0. However, I am having issue finding the coordinates of the first 0-value pixel of the object I want to trace within the image.

I tried:

```
[row, column] = find(bw, 1, 'last')
```

but of course, this just gives me the coordinates of the last pixel that has a value of one.

And this doesn't work:

```
[row, column] = find(bw, 0, 'last')
```

I want to find the coordinates of a 0-value pixel in order to trace the region and "detect" the region within the image.

Thanks!

Comment: Try this instead - `[row, column] = find(bw==0, 1, 'last')` for the last pixel with 0 value? Edit `'last'` to `'first'` for the first pixel with 0 value.

Comment: How do you define "first" in two dimensions?

Comment: Hello! I actually just ended up reversing the image, but thank you for the advice!